# Different languages in subject line and text body in outlook 2003

Tags: microsoft-outlook, localization

I am not an exchange admin in my organisation but I wondered if you can find a solution to this.

When I send an email through Outlook 2003 (using Word 2003 to compose my mail) I get the subject checked in US English and the Body spell checked in UK English.

Tools|options|spelling shows my language as UK English.

Windows XP's regional settings says that I am using UK English. Normal.dot is using UK English. The exchange server's regional settings says UK English.

How can I make sure that the subject is UK English?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have here is most likely that you are using word as your email editor, so Outlook uses the dictionary set in word for the body of the email, which will be UK English, however the spell checking in the subject line is done by Outlook itself, which is probably set to US English.

To change Outlooks language (in Outlook 2007), go to Tools, Options, Spelling Tab, Spelling and AutoCorrection - In this new menu you will see in the middle section "Custom Dictionaries." Click this button and then use the drop down menu at the bottom of the next screen to set Dictionary Language to English UK.

In Outlook 2003, you need to take a look in c:\program files\microsoft office\office11\1033. In here should be a file called email.dot, right click on the file and go to 'open the file', do not double click. In here in the status bar at the bottom it should show "English (US)", double click on this and change to English (UK). Save and close, it should now have the right dictionary.

Comment: As stated I am using Outlook 2003. In tools, options, spelling and AutoCorrection it does not have the middle section Custom Dictionaries, however the title states the language is English (U.K.)

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the Outlook 2003, please see amended answer

Comment: This looks like it should be the correct solution. Don't know why its not working for me.

Comment: how can I solve this in Outlook 2016 ?

Answer (score 1):

If you go into 'Control Panel', head into 'Region and Language' and then select the 'Administrative' tab - I highly suspect your 'Language for Non-unicode programs' system locale setting will be configured as "English (United States)". Fix it and reboot.

Comment: In Windows 10 this can be accessed by settings > Region, then clicking the "Additional date, time & regional settings" link  which takes you to the "old" control panel > Region > Administrative

Answer (score 0):

See http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/spelling-in-subject-line-and-message-body-in/ea9895f1-ba24-429f-804c-24d0845e6f5b?msgId=4c4f13ce-51b1-47a8-87ea-a18977b0cf1c It seems we have to bombard MS with proposals to change this

Answer (score 0):

I've been plagued by asking Outlook (MAC OS 11.6) to auto detect message body. I write in English and Spanish frequently. No matter what I do, the subject line always auto corrects to Spanish resulting in many unwanted odd subject lines. I went to System Preferences, Language and Region,Keyboard Preferences, Text tab, and changed 'spelling' to English. These seems to have resolved the issue. A test message still seemed to auto detect Spanish in the body email, but leave the English subject line alone.
Hope this helps someone.